# memory error when using gensim for loading word2vec

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding, google-news

I am using gensim library for loading pre-trained word vectors from GoogleNews dataset. this dataset contains 3000000 word vectors each of 300 dimensions. when I want to load GoogleNews dataset, I receive a memory error. I have tried this code before without memory error and I don't know why I receive this error now.
I have checked a lot of sites for solving this issue but I cant understand.
this is my code for loading GoogleNews:

```
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec
model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin",binary=True)
```

and this is the error I received:

```
File "/home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/tensor_env_project/word_embedding_DUC2007/inspect_word2vec-master/word_embeddings_GoogleNews.py", line 8, in <module>
    model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin",binary=True)
  File "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 212, in load_word2vec_format
    result.syn0 = zeros((vocab_size, vector_size), dtype=datatype)
MemoryError
```

can anybody help me? thanks.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit python or 64-bit python?

Comment: I checked it by `import platform platform.architecture()` and the result was 64 bit python.

Comment: I updated `gensim`, `numpy` and `scipy` packages and restart my computer. and now I don't have that problem. but I don't know what happened. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Loading just the raw vectors will take...

3,000,000 words * 300 dimensions * 4 bytes/dimension = 3.6GB

...of addressable memory (plus some overhead for the word-key to index-position map).

Additionally, as soon as you want to do a `most_similar()`-type operation, unit-length normalized versions of the vectors will be created – which will require another 3.6GB. (You may instead clobber the raw vectors in place, saving that extra memory, if you'll only be doing cosine-similarity comparisons between the unit-normed vectors, by 1st doing a forced explicit `model.init_sims(replace=True)`.)

So you'll generally only want to do full operations on a machine with at least 8GB of RAM. (Any swapping at all during full-array `most_similar()` lookups will make operations very slow.)

If anything else was using Python heap space, that could have accounted for the `MemoryError` you saw.

The `load_word2vec_format()` method also has an optional `limit` argument which will only load the supplied number of vectors – so you could use `limit=500000` to cut the memory requirements by about 5/6ths. (And, since the `GoogleNews` and other vector sets are usually ordered from most- to least-frequent words, you'll get the 500K most-frequent words. Lower-frequency words generally have much less value and even not-as-good vectors, so it may not hurt much to ignore them.)

Comment: Silly question, but I want to use this Google News model over various different files on my laptop. This means I will be running this line over and over again in different Jupyter notebooks: 

model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin",binary=True)

Does this eat 1) Storage (I've noticed my storage filling up exponentially for no reason) and 2) memory if I close the previous notebook before running the next.

Comment: Just loading a model won't usually use any more disk storage. (An exception: if load or use needs addressable memory beyond your RAM, you may start using virtual memory, which might show up as less-disk space depending on your OS. But, with these sorts of models, you want to avoid using any virtual memory, as basic `most_similar()` ops cycle through the full model, & will be very slow.) Loading the model will use memory, then more when 1st doing `most_similar()` – but terminating a notebook should free that memory. (Note closing a tab may not cleanly terminate a Jupyter notebook.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

To load the whole model one needs a bigger RAM.

You may use the following code. Set the limit to which your system can take. It'll load vectors that are at top of the file.

```
from gensim import models

w = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r"GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True, limit = 100000)
```

I set the limit as 100,000. It worked on my 4GB RAM laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all your browser tabs and everything else that is eating up RAM. For me that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the RAM it would work

Comment: Although you are correct, your answer would be a bit more helpful for the poster if you could clarify what you mean by "increase the ram" and also explain to them more of what is happening.

Comment: Is there any method so we can generalize another model from the pretrained word2vec model so we can predict similar items without heavy usage of RAM ?